# What does (0, _redux.createStore) mean in Javascript generated by Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, redux

I am a beginner in ES6 and I was checking out Babel 6. 
I imported Redux using the statement

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
```

and later used it like this

```
const store = createStore(myReducer);
```

When I ran Babel with ES2015 plugin, it transformed the code to

```
var store = (0, _redux.createStore)(myReducer);
```

What does this `(0, _redux.createStore)` mean ?

Comment: In that form, `(0, ..)` is a sequence expression (surrounded by parenthesis). It evaluates to the last expression - consider: `1 === (3,2,1)`. The last expression evaluates to a function which is invoked, but I'm not sure why the form is used over a more direct-looking `(_redux.createStore)(..)`. Remember that it is function *objects/values* - as resulting from any expression - that are invoked.

Comment: IIRC, I have a very vague recollection of changing the `this` binding in strict/non-strict modes.. although https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator says nothing on the topic.

Comment: Whoop! Found it :D

Answer (score 0):

> What does this (0, _redux.createStore) mean ?

Babel transpiled the imported value of `redux` into a temporary variable `_redux` and then uses that for any references that chain off of `_redux` e.g. `createStore`. So we have `_redux.createStore`.

This helps preserve *context* ([a video on `this` is helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA)) on the called function.

Comment: An output of `_redux.createStore(myReducer)` would still make the first part of the answer true .. and yet it says nothing about the sequence grammar expression / comma operator used.